# Jquery - Hover effect not working when loading dynamic content - URI with hastags

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, hover

I am currently working the front-end on a website.
I am using jquery in order to create a dynamic content.

My problem is that when I type my URI (localhost/jquery/myfile/) and the index.php loads, my jquery script works, but when I click on my navigation bar and my #index.php is placed in the URI (localhost/jquery/myfile/#index.php) one of my js scripts, the one with the hover effect, doesn't work (but all my other js files work, such as my nav menu script which includes a hover effect as well).

I have made my research and found out that when the new URI is loaded, hover effect stops working.

**index.php**

```
<section id="main-content">
<div id="guts">
    <div id="items">
        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span style="display: none;" class="caption">8 Extremely </span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span class="caption">8 Amazing Javascript Experiments of Physic and Gravity Simulation</span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span class="caption">8 Incredible Wordpress Plugins</span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span class="caption">9 Web CSS Tools You Must Know</span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span style="display: none;" class="caption">10 Image Galleries jQuery Script with Thumbnail Filmstrip</span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span style="display: none;" class="caption">Single Page Websites With Creative Javascript Effects</span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span class="caption">13 Simple but Useful Online Tools for Web Development</span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span class="caption">8 Ways to Increase the Readibility and Beautify your HTML Code</span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span class="caption">12 Insanely Awesome Javascript Effects</span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span style="display: none;" class="caption">10 New jQuery Plugins You Have to Know</span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span class="caption">20 Firefox Plug-ins for Web Designers and Developers</span></a>

        <a style="opacity: 1;" class="item" href="#" title="">
        <img src="#" width="190" height="120">
        <span class="caption">12 Amazing and Creative Javascript Games</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

**ext.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//loop through all the children in #items
//save title value to a span and then remove the value of the title to avoid tooltips
$('#items .item').each(function () {
    title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).append('<span class="caption">' + title + '</span>');  
    $(this).attr('title','');
});

$('#items .item').hover(
    function () {
        //set the opacity of all siblings
        $(this).siblings().css({'opacity': '0.2'});

        //set the opacity of current item to full, and add the effect class
        $(this).css({'opacity': '1.0'}).addClass('effect');

        //show the caption
        $(this).children('.caption').show();   
    },
    function () {
        //hide the caption
        $(this).children('.caption').hide();       
    }
);

$('#items').mouseleave(function () {
    //reset all the opacity to full and remove effect class
    $(this).children().fadeTo('100', '1.0').removeClass('effect');     
});   
});
```

**dynamicpage.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight   = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        $("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
});
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me find why this is happening.

Thanks in advance,
harris21

**edit:**My dynamic menu is working fine, the problem is that the the ext.js script is not working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using on() if you are using a recent version of jQuery (1.7+), or delegate() if its an older version, instead of just hover()

Like this:

```
$("#main-content").on("mouseenter", "#items .item", function(event){
// your function
}).on("mouseleave", "#items .item", function(event){
// your function
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I have read about on() function , but when I use it the ext.js script doesn't even load, not even when the simple URI (without the hashtags) is loaded. 
Do you thing that the ext.js script need any changes regarding the on() function?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? do you see any errors in console when you use on?

Comment: I have the newest version. Funny thing is, no error is showing up :S

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say ext.js doesn't load? Isn't it already loaded at that point. The page has not reloaded when you click you navigation, you have just refreshed the content of an element, right?

Comment: Yes, ext.js is working.
When the URI is : localhost/jquery/myfile/ , hover effect is working fine. But when I click my nav button and the URI becomes : localhost/jquery/myfile/#index.php, then the hover effect from the images isn't working at all. The nav bar hover effect is working like a charm though.

Comment: You said above that ext.js was not loading when you use on(). That is what I was asking about. The situation (If I am understanding you) is that you are introducing new elements to the page and expecting a hover affect triggered by an event handler that has been established with .hover(). I would not expect that to work since those new elements where not around to receive the event handler on load. This is why you need either on() or delegate(). Assuming there is no other issue with your script (which would appear in console) and you are using the right selectors, one or the other should work.

Comment: [`.on('hover')` no longer works as of jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes) -- you have to delegate `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` separately.

Answer (score 0):

When working with dynamic content be sure to use `jquery.on` (the newer version of live).

```
$.on('click', function(){

});
```

instead of

```
$.click(function(){});
```

Comment: I have read about on() function , but when I use it the ext.js script doesn't even load, not even when the simple URI (without the hashtags) is loaded.
Do you thing that the ext.js script need any changes regarding the on() function?

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution for this problem.

```
$(document).on("mousemove",".objectclass",function(){
   console.log("mousemove");
});
```

its works fine!